# how to combine the two connections (wireless connection and modem connection) into a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, wireless-access-point, usb-modem

My modem connection is very slow and I wanted to combine speed with wireless connection, i use windows 7 for the operating system. is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is there a fast wifi network there? Why not simply connecting to the wifi network anyway? If the wifi is also slow, connecting to both would only gives you the combined speed of the slow wifi and slow modem connection

Comment: I want to get a fast connection by combining two slow connection, is it possible?

Comment: Where are you getting the wireless connection?  If it's WiFi from your modem you won't do any better -- the wireless will just compete with the hard-wired connection for channel space.  If it's WiFi "borrowed" from somewhere else, or a cell phone modem connection, then you might be able to effectively use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all you get is the combined speed anyway. Nothing special, just connect to both at once. Do note that Windows (and other OS too) tends to favor the wifi, so unless your application are using all bandwidth available to the wifi, the modem won't be used. Now, since the connection is 'slow' for you, the application would be using both connection at once. Additionally, set both connection to the same location (Home or Public. Public seems appropriate, since you probably don't want the ISP to look at your public share folder).
Another one, several download sites open a special connection that can only be used by a single IP. Those won't use the multiple connection, since each connection would have different IP.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be yes.  There's a few ways to do this with different results.. You could specific which programs use which IP/connection so say you are streaming movies you coudl have it only use one and then specific the other connection for everything else

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/28798-42-wired-wireless-connection-laptop - good thread talking about this

http://www.kerio.com/control/qos - This software claims to be able to load-balance multiple connections

Answer (score -1):

The short answer would be no.  Assuming you are talking about connecting to the Internet, you cannot combine connections.

Comment: is there any other solutions such as using software ?